# Adding Fragments to the Activity's root view

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-view

Is it safe to assume that an `Activity`'s root view will always be a `ViewGroup`? I have an `Activity` that displays various `Fragment`s. Can I skip creating a layout XML for the `Activity` and directly add `Fragment`s to its root view?

Comment: Why would you want to? And maybe, I am not sure  what happens if you set no layout, but it definitely works if you set one. But then again what reason would there be to do this in the first place?

Comment: I don't need any other UI elements in the Activity. I just need to navigate from one Fragment to the next.

Comment: So? Isn't that what you are supposed to do anyway? You need some layout to perform `FragmentTransactions`. Why would you want to use some `View` further up in the `View` hierarchy instead of just having an `Activity` with just a `FrameLayout` or something like that? What you are planning to do can potentially be very difficult to get to work on most devices. Implementations change a lot across API levels and OEMs.

Comment: It's officially recommended to use a <merge> element as the XML root if possible instead of wrapping everything in a Layout. This directly stuffs alls the Views in the  XML into the Activity's root View. This implies that the root View will always be a FrameLayout.

Comment: A few days ago I wrote an answer on how to create a sliding menu that pushes the `Activity` to the side instead of overlapping it like the `NavigationDrawer`. It is based on the same thing you are asking about, you can take a look maybe it helps you: [**Link**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23783496/how-to-slide-the-actionbar-along-with-the-navigationdrawer/23954699#23954699)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

yes it does work.
The Activity root will always be a ViewGroup (otherwise how would you or the framework be able to put other views inside it when inflating the XML?)

Furthermore (to make the answer complete), it's a well known/well documented ID

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(android.R.id.content, fragment)
    .commit();
```

ps.: the above code was written without looking up, so there might be some typo, somewhere.

Comment: replace(android.R.id.content, fragment) is exactly what I wanted!

Comment: I've done this in a few apps already (including the one I currently work on that have more than half a million downloads), so use it without worries.