# How to slide the Activity along with the NavigationDrawer from right side?

Tags: android, facebook, navigation-drawer

I want to implement the Sliding NavigationDrawer in my app which is similar to facebook app, I did some research on how to do this and found answer from this question [How to slide the ActionBar along with the NavigationDrawer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23783496/how-to-slide-the-actionbar-along-with-the-navigationdrawer) as per this answer I implemented the NavigationDrawer where the menu gets slide from the left side but i want it to slide from right side how to achieve it ?

Awaiting for the answer!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is as simple as left drawer

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
 android:id="@+id/content_frame"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<ListView
 android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
 android:layout_width="400dp"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:layout_gravity="start"
 android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
 android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
 android:dividerHeight="0dp"
 android:background="#111"/>

<ListView
 android:id="@+id/right_drawer"
 android:layout_width="400dp"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:layout_gravity="end"
 android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
 android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
 android:dividerHeight="0dp"
 android:background="#111"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and initialize it same as left drawer.

refer this  [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.DrawerListener.html)

Then  implement 
`onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset)`.

And add line `mDrawerLayout.findViewById(R.id.main_contain_id).setTranslationX(drawerView.getWidth() * slideOffset);`

Comment: Thanks for the response but the thing is i want the NavigationDrawer similar to the facebook application i.e, the complete ActionBar should also move along with the NavigationDrawer  where as default android DrawerLayout will not provide this behavior. Check with this image i need this behavior [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/wYSpD.gif)

Comment: I have updated my answer as you want , Please check it

Comment: No that doesn't help me.