# How to show SlidingPaneLayout at right side?

Tags: android, slidingmenu

Hi I am a beginner for android and in my app I have to show SlidingPaneLayout at the right side but using my below code it's coming from left side.

Please help me.

How can I make it be at right side?

And second my requirement is my SlidingPaneLayout must be overlapped on Action bar but using my below xml code SlidingPaneLayout showing like my below image

please suggest me how can resolve this two problem

### toolbar_layout:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    >

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

### activity_sliding:-

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/SlidingPanel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/MenuList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        </ListView>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:background="#101010"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/android_robot" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout>
```

### main_layout:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_layout">
    </include>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/SlidingPanel"
        layout="@layout/activity_sliding">
    </include>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: What's your `minSdkVersion`?

Comment: Looks like a navigation drawer.

Comment: minSdkVersion is  23 @Mike M

Comment: @Raghunadan it's SlidingPaneLayout not navigation Drawer

Comment: @Raghunandan Yeah, I thought so, too, but `SlidingPaneLayout` has a different movement behavior. I'd never used it until just now.

Comment: and i want to show that SlidingPaneLayout at right side instead of left side

Comment: @Krish What do you mean by "SlidingPaneLayout must be overlapped on Action bar", exactly?

Comment: i mean when i opened my SlidingPaneLayout then ActionBar also need to move along with SlidingPaneLayout

Comment: that's what my second requirement

Comment: but present i want to show SlidingPaneLayout at right side instead of left side

Comment: Hi mike m u there?

Comment: Gimme a minute. I'm on a phone, atm.

Comment: ok ok sure i am waiting and i hope i will help me

Comment: @Krish you have set gravity right for both your linerlayouts. i think one of them should be left

Comment: which one should be left?

Comment: and first i want to know is it possible to show at right side?

Comment: @Krish it is possible and use start and end instead of left and right

Comment: no i used end instead of right but no use and ur free now?

Comment: @Krish i am not saying that's gonna solve your problem but it is best you use start and end instead of left or right

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109301/discussion-between-krish-and-raghunandan).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your manifest, add the following attribute to the opening `<application>` tag.

```
android:supportsRtl="true"
```

Then add this attribute to the opening `SlidingPaneLayout` tag in your layout.

```
android:layoutDirection="rtl"
```

And finally, move the `tool_bar` `<include>` element into the main content `LinearLayout` within the `SlidingPaneLayout`, and adjust the `ImageView`'s height and weight.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#101010"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_layout">
    </include>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/android_robot" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Please note that the child `View`s of the `SlidingPaneLayout` will inherit the `rtl` `layoutDirection`. This may cause problems in child `View`s if their layout behavior is affected by the direction. For example, a horizontally-oriented `LinearLayout` will lay out its children starting from the right. This is easily remedied by setting `android:layoutDirection="ltr"` on the affected `View`s.

Also note that this example hard codes the direction in the layout. If you need to support both LTR and RTL layouts application-wide, you'll need to do this programmatically, accounting for the device's default direction.

Comment: i am not sure if it helps. but check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23783496/how-to-slide-the-actionbar-along-with-the-navigationdrawer.

Comment: but major problem is i want to show SliderLayoutPanel at right side

Comment: @Krish The RTL layout worked for me. You sure you've got the attributes in the right places?

Comment: @MikeM. he has android:layout_gravity="right for both linearlayouts

Comment: @Krish If this doesn't work for you, you might be stuck with using a `DrawerLayout` with a right drawer `View`. I have a solution for that which is very similar to the `SlidingPaneLayout` behavior.

Comment: @Raghunandan From what I can tell, `SlidingPaneLayout` ignores the `layout_gravity` attributes. It just goes by the order of the child `View`s. But they should probably get rid of them anyway.

Comment: @MikeM. agreed its after all a viewgroup

Comment: @Krish I added some notes to the answer that you might need to be aware of.

Comment: One thing is that, using android:layoutDirection="rtl" needs minimum sdk version 17 while I am using 13. Is this the only way for solving problem?

Comment: @Patzu Almost certainly not, but this was a one-off solution for a `minSdkVersion` of 23. For anything below 17, apart from just writing your own class from scratch, you'd probably need to subclass `SlidingPaneLayout`, which might get a little hairy.