# Move action bar along with Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, drawerlayout, navigation-drawer, android-actionbaractivity

I have implemented Navigation bar as per google guildlines but i want to move action bar along with drawer. I have even referred following [How to slide the ActionBar along with the NavigationDrawer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23783496/how-to-slide-the-actionbar-along-with-the-navigationdrawer) but not able to achieve it.

**i want to achieve something like below without using third parties lib:**

[image]

**DrawerActivity:**

```
public  abstract class BarcodeBaseActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

 setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
//        setTypface();

        mTitle = getTitle();
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
//        drawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open,
                R.string.navigation_drawer_close) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
                history.setSelected(false);
                help.setSelected(false);
                unipoints.setSelected(false);
                promotions.setSelected(false);
                notifications.setSelected(false);
                info.setSelected(false);
                contact.setSelected(false);
                signout.setSelected(false);
                drawerOpened = false;
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                history.setSelected(true);
                help.setSelected(true);
                unipoints.setSelected(true);
                promotions.setSelected(true);
                notifications.setSelected(true);
                info.setSelected(true);
                contact.setSelected(true);
                signout.setSelected(true);
                drawerOpened = true;
            }

            public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
        mDrawerToggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.burger);
        ValueAnimator anim = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0, 1);
        anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                float slideOffset = (Float) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
                mDrawerToggle.onDrawerSlide(drawerLayout, slideOffset);
            }
        });
        anim.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());

// You can change this duration to more closely match that of the default animation.
        anim.setDuration(500);
        anim.start();
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
            }
        });

        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
//        drawerLayout.setStatusBarBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));

        drawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawer_list);
        View list_header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.drawerlist_header, null);
  drawerItems = getDrawerItems(pos);
        drawerList.setAdapter(new DrawerListAdapter(this, getLayoutInflater(), drawerItems));
        drawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());


        if (drawerOpened) {
            history.setSelected(false);
            help.setSelected(false);
            unipoints.setSelected(false);
            promotions.setSelected(false);
            notifications.setSelected(false);
            info.setSelected(false);
            contact.setSelected(false);
            signout.setSelected(false);
        } else {
            history.setSelected(true);
            help.setSelected(true);
            unipoints.setSelected(true);
            promotions.setSelected(true);
            notifications.setSelected(true);
            info.setSelected(true);
            contact.setSelected(true);
            signout.setSelected(true);
        }

        setTitle(mTitle);
    }

  @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }


 private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Log.d(BarcodeBaseActivity.class.getSimpleName(), "Drawer item clicked at position " + position);

            /*for (DrawerItem drawerItem : drawerItems) {
                drawerItem.setSelected(false);
            }

            DrawerItem drawerItem = drawerItems.get(position - 1);
            drawerItem.setSelected(true);

            HeaderViewListAdapter headerViewListAdapter = (HeaderViewListAdapter) drawerList.getAdapter();
            DrawerListAdapter drawerListAdapter = (DrawerListAdapter) headerViewListAdapter.getWrappedAdapter();
            drawerListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
*/
            selectItem(position);
            for (DrawerItem drawerItem : drawerItems) {
                drawerItem.setSelected(false);
            }
            if (position > 0) {
                DrawerItem drawerItem = drawerItems.get(position - 1);
                drawerItem.setSelected(true);

            }
            updateDrawer();
            SharedPreferences.Editor sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(AppConstants.PREFERENCE_SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            sharedPreferences.putInt(AppConstants.PREFERENCE_LAST_DRAWERITEM_CLICKED, position - 1);
            sharedPreferences.commit();
        }
    }
```

Please help me with some snippet.

Comment: I don't think that's the way things must be done. What are you trying to achieve IOS app on Android?

Comment: @YuriiTsap but there are lots of Android app as well who have implemented same as ios apps. So this implies it can implement in android as well

Comment: Yes, could be, but why for do you need IOS design. We have our own - Material. As for fum - you can try to achieve this - but for real world app - not the best approach. You can try a lot of  hacks with Window Manager flags and also have a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/23954699/3874721

Comment: @YuriiTsap : i know this is not as per the Android guild lines but my ui is such that i have to achieve same. Otherwise i am also happy to use the default one.Also, i have implemented above answer too but its not working like i want

Comment: The problem is you do not have a simple and straightforward solution. Everything else will be just a hack. As I said you need to play with Window Manager. Maybe you should consider on hiding the actual status bar and build your own and after that you can just overlap it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SlidingPanelayout provided by Android instead of using Navigation Drawer.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SlidingPaneLayout.html

http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2013/10/android-slidingpanelayout-tutorial-2.html

Comment: SlidingPaneLayout doesnt move action bar. And i want to move action bar along with drawer

Comment: You can use toolbar instead of default action bar, you need to add toolbar in the second layout of slidingPaneLayout.

Comment: i dont get it. what second layout?

Comment: SlidingPaneLayout has 2 sub layouts, 1st as left layout and 2nd as Right Layout. By Default, the Right layout is shown and when the slidingpanelayout is opened, then left comes out and right pushes to more right. You need to add the toolbar to right layout.

Comment: I am trying to achieve with Sliding pane but i guess it wont give me wat i want.

Comment: thank you , your suggestion helped. I accept your answer. Also , if you could upvote my question i will be grateful

Answer (score -1):

Add this to your `Drawer` `Callbacks`

```
@Override
public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
    View container = findViewById(R.id.container);
    container.setTranslationX(slideOffset * drawerView.getWidth() * -1);
}
```

Comment: whats this container?