# Android DrawerLayout not sliding actionbar

Tags: java, android

i have created a slidermenu but the issue i am having is that it does not slide the action bar?

It only slides the content.

Here is my xml of the activity

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout

        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.me.ui.MainActivity">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </LinearLayout>


    </FrameLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/side_menu"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/slide_menu_width"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@null"></ListView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

The "native" navigation drawer is intended to slide only the content, not the actionbar.
Some early implementations (i.e. not official) allowed the actionbar to be slided too, but the implementation provided by the support library does not.

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16949512/getting-drawerlayout-to-slide-over-the-actionbar) for example.

Comment: Maybe bad design practise to slide the action bar?

Comment: I would not call it bad (or good) design, but it is not what the majority of the users will expect since the common behaviour is not to slide it