# Is possible use Drawer Navigation, ViewPager, TabHost ( or FragmentTabHost) and Fragments (v4)

Tags: android-viewpager, android-tabhost, drawerlayout

Well friends..
hi everybody!

I have a great question... and i don't know if this is possible..
i've been looking for info about this but really i don't found...
Anyone knowns anything about this ?

I've been use this:

```
http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html
```

and this:
[enter link description here](http://www.androidcurso.com/index.php/recursos-didacticos/tutoriales-android/32-unidad-2-diseno-de-la-interfaz-de-usuario-vistas-y-layouts/213-uso-de-tabhost)
Thx 4 advance!

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible but it's quite complicated. I would recommend you the following links

- http://www.michenux.net/android-navigation-drawer-748.html
- https://github.com/Balaji-K13/Navigation-drawer-page-sliding-tab-strip/blob/master/src/com/webileapps/navdrawer/MainActivity.java from Balaji who has developped a demo available on github with the features you are looking for.

When using the drawer along with tabs, the drawer menu is displayed below the tabs. The main discussions about this issue are:

- [Android Navigation Drawer over the tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16713530/android-navigation-drawer-over-the-tabs)
- [Getting DrawerLayout to Slide over the ActionBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16949512/getting-drawerlayout-to-slide-over-the-actionbar/16949684#16949684)