# Is it possible to implement Tab Host on action-bar in android?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, navigation-drawer, fragment-tab-host

I have implemented tab host with navigation drawer using ActionBarShaerlock. Currently element to open navigation drawer on action bar and tab host in bottom of it.

[image: Screenshot]

I want tabs in actionbar. It it possible to do so?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html.check  Adding Navigation tabs. You have the drawer so why do you need tabs. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16713530/android-navigation-drawer-over-the-tabs

Comment: are you looking for tabs just below action bar?

Comment: I have already implemented as shown in the scrrenshot using actionbarsherlock , however i am looking for implementing DrawerMenu and Tabhost on actionbar(On single Line).

Answer (score 0):

you can add tabs below action bar using something like this-

```
  ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

Tab tab = actionBar.newTab()
                   .setText(R.string.artist)
                   .setTabListener(new TabListener<ArtistFragment>(
                           this, "artist", ArtistFragment.class));
actionBar.addTab(tab);

tab = actionBar.newTab()
               .setText(R.string.album)
               .setTabListener(new TabListener<AlbumFragment>(
                       this, "album", AlbumFragment.class));
actionBar.addTab(tab);
```

see this link [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html)

hope this will help you.

Comment: actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS); now it's deprecated!