# How to have swiping tabs and navigation drawer together in a android app?

Tags: android, android-tabs

How to have swiping `tabs` and `navigation drawer` together in a app? I am having a problem in my project, any proper tutorial for how to create that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been asked dozens of times. Consider using google or searching StackOverflow before posting a question.

You can find a good answer here: [Android Navigation Drawer over the tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16713530/android-navigation-drawer-over-the-tabs).  Basically, you shouldn't use both navigation drawer and tabs with the stock version.

If you want to do it (like google play store) you should implement your own versions, or use one of the plenty of libs readily available, for example http://viewpagerindicator.com/

Comment: Thanks a lot brunorey, I did try searching it elsewhere before Posting this question but couldn't find much. And I have read a blog where they have mentioned that we should not use swiping tabs and navigation drawer together but its our software's requirement so I needed it.