# Tabs in a tabbed activity disappear when the hamburger menu is opened

Tags: android, tabs, navigation-drawer, android-tabs

I have a tabbed activity with a hamburger menu. When I open the hamburger menu, the tabs disappear. Although the content doesn't vanish, the disappearance of tabs results in a frustrating experience for the user. I have posted code snippets below and will give additional code if needed. Please help me.

**The Activity**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.sample.R;

public class TabbedActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener,
        NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    private String[] tabs = {"Occasions", "Categories"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tabbed);

        final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
        mTitle = getTitle();

        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
                R.id.navigation_drawer,
                (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));

        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            }
        });

        for (String tabName : tabs) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tabName).setTabListener(this));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    }

    public void restoreActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_home, menu);
            restoreActionBar();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.actionSearch) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, SearchActivity.class));
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

}
```

**Corresponding XML file**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".view.TabbedActivity">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:name=".view.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigationDrawerWidth"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**GIF to show how it works**

[image]

Comment: can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Yes I will. Just converting to a GIF and I'll update it.

Comment: @BasimSherif I added the gif

Comment: check this answer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16713530/android-navigation-drawer-over-the-tabs

Comment: But the tabs are not disappearing for him. Why is it disappearing for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16718158/1416629

> I got the same issue and the answer I got from Roman Nurik (Android team) is that the Navigation Drawer should not be used with the Action Bar tabs.